# A million of rows in ExtJS infinite grid (strange effect)

Tags: extjs

I've made an application with `ExtJS infinite grid` like [this example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/infinite-scroll.js).

My application receives data from a database.

It worked perfectly with the small amounts of rows (by 100000).

But now a database contains one million of rows. And I observed a strange effect: data are not loaded completely. Each time the grid shows different number of rows (maximum 859176). But I need to load all rows from a database.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

My code:

```
Ext.require ([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer'
]);

Ext.onReady(function () {

    Ext.define('DoctorsList', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'id', 'fio', 'specialization', 'photo'
        ],
        idProperty: 'id'
    });

    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id: 'store',
        model: 'DoctorsList',
        buffered: true,
        pageSize: 100,
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: 'get_doctors.jsp',
            reader: {
                root: 'data',
                totalProperty: 'total'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });

    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        height: 600,
        title: 'Doctor\'s list',
        collapsible: true,
        store: store,
        columns: [
        {
            text: 'ID',
            dataIndex: 'id',
            width: 50,
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Full name',
            dataIndex: 'fio',
            width: 300,
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Specialization',
            dataIndex: 'specialization',
            width: 150,
            sortable: true
        },
        {
            text: 'Photo',
            dataIndex: 'photo',
            width: 100,
            sortable: false,
            renderer: function(value) {
                return '<img width="100" src="images/' + value + '" />';
            }
        }
        ],
        renderTo: 'doctors-list'
    });

});
```

ADDITION:

[Here](http://postimg.org/image/54yx546hn/) you can see last request and response to get_doctors.jsp. You can notice there that the field 'total' has number 1005000 but last row has ID 423165. And [here](http://postimg.org/image/t1uja5a07/) is the screen of MS SQL database selection. You can see there that used table has 1005000 rows totally.

ADDITION 2:
This bug appears in Firefox and IE8, but it does not appear in Opera, Google Chrome and Safari.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you check what went over the network to make sure there were actually 1m items?

Comment: Yes, please post the network request(s) and response(s) to get_doctors.jsp You can find them in the Network panel of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: who in the real world needs 1m records brought to the client?

Comment: @dbrin , I really don't know but it's my task. I have to do it.

Comment: @usr you can see requests and responses on the screenshot in the end of the post.

Comment: You could implement remote paging instead so you are only bringing back 100-200 rows from the DB at a time

Comment: i totally agree that you need to build paging for this list, and if the purpose of having all the records is JS-search, better implement that remotely as well! 1m rows is a LOT of data that might run slow over internet (if every row was in avg 100byte thats a 100MB in that list !!)

Comment: I guess you need set that plugin for the grid `plugins: 'bufferedrenderer'`, as showed on this [page](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.1/examples/grid/buffer-grid.html).